# Php multi curl - get stuff while multi curl is running

Tags: php, curl-multi

I am designing a simple scraping parser with multi curl. I have see many example, but there is a little problem. The parser is waiting of the slowest response and after that is beginning with the parsing.

Is there some cool method to begin with the parsing while the multi curl is still running? Because if the slowest request is 10 seconds, then the whole script is waiting 10 seconds and afterthat is beginning with the parsing of the sources.

Thanks
Nik

Answer (score 0):

See http://www.jaisenmathai.com/articles/php-curl-asynchronous.html
TL;DR: curl_multi_exec lets you check whether any request is ready.